# custom wcf binding set dynamically from code

Tags: workflow, custom-actions, wcf

I am developing a workflow custom action that uses a wcf webservice.
The thing is, I have no proper way to attach the app.config file so I'd have to generate the bindings and the client endpoints manually from code.

Here's what I'm talking about:

```
    <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                allowCookies="false">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                    enabled="false" />
                <security mode="Message">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                        algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:55693/Service1.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
            name="WSHttpBinding_IService1">
            <identity>
                <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

How to do that? Would anyone give me any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though not an exact answer but you can get a head on your approach by the following example available on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.wshttpbinding.aspx) , using the WSHTTPBinding programatecally.

```
              public sealed class CustomBindingCreator
              {

        public static void snippetSecurity()
        {
            WSHttpBinding wsHttpBinding = new WSHttpBinding();
            WSHttpSecurity whSecurity = wsHttpBinding.Security;
        }


        public static void snippetCreateBindingElements()
        {
            WSHttpBinding wsHttpBinding = new WSHttpBinding();
            BindingElementCollection beCollection = wsHttpBinding.CreateBindingElements();
        }


        private void snippetCreateMessageSecurity()
        {
            WSHttpBinding wsHttpBinding = new WSHttpBinding();
            // SecurityBindingElement sbe = wsHttpBinding
        }

        public static void snippetGetTransport()
        {
            WSHttpBinding wsHttpBinding = new WSHttpBinding();
            //      TransportBindingElement tbElement = wsHttpBinding.GetTransport();
        }

        public static void snippetAllowCookies()
        {
            WSHttpBinding wsHttpBinding = new WSHttpBinding();
            wsHttpBinding.AllowCookies = true;
        }

        public static Binding GetBinding()
        {
            // securityMode is Message 
            // reliableSessionEnabled is true
            WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.Message, true);
            binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Windows;

            WSHttpSecurity security = binding.Security;
            return binding;

        }

        public static Binding GetBinding2()
        {

            // The security mode is set to Message.
            WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.Message);
            binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Windows;
            return binding;

        }

        // This method creates a WSFederationHttpBinding. 
        public static WSFederationHttpBinding CreateWSFederationHttpBinding()
        {
            // Create an instance of the WSFederationHttpBinding
            WSFederationHttpBinding b = new WSFederationHttpBinding();

            // Set the security mode to Message
            b.Security.Mode = WSFederationHttpSecurityMode.Message;

            // Set the Algorithm Suite to Basic256Rsa15
            b.Security.Message.AlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic256Rsa15;

            // Set NegotiateServiceCredential to true
            b.Security.Message.NegotiateServiceCredential = true;

            // Set IssuedKeyType to Symmetric
            b.Security.Message.IssuedKeyType = SecurityKeyType.SymmetricKey;

            // Set IssuedTokenType to SAML 1.1
            b.Security.Message.IssuedTokenType = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#samlv1.1";

            // Extract the STS certificate from the certificate store
            X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.TrustedPeople, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            X509Certificate2Collection certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "cd 54 88 85 0d 63 db ac 92 59 05 af ce b8 b1 de c3 67 9e 3f", false);
            store.Close();

            // Create an EndpointIdentity from the STS certificate
            EndpointIdentity identity = EndpointIdentity.CreateX509CertificateIdentity(certs[0]);

            // Set the IssuerAddress using the address of the STS and the previously created EndpointIdentity
            b.Security.Message.IssuerAddress = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://localhost:8000/sts/x509"), identity);

            // Set the IssuerBinding to a WSHttpBinding loaded from config
            b.Security.Message.IssuerBinding = new WSHttpBinding("Issuer");

            // Set the IssuerMetadataAddress using the metadata address of the STS and the previously created EndpointIdentity
            b.Security.Message.IssuerMetadataAddress = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://localhost:8001/sts/mex"), identity);

            // Create a ClaimTypeRequirement
            ClaimTypeRequirement ctr = new ClaimTypeRequirement("http://example.org/claim/c1", false);

            // Add the ClaimTypeRequirement to ClaimTypeRequirements
            b.Security.Message.ClaimTypeRequirements.Add(ctr);

            // Return the created binding 
            return b;
        }

    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes exactly what I needed, I did `WSHttpBinding myBinding = new WSHttpBinding()`, set up myBinding's properties, initialized `EndpointAddress myEndpoint = new EndpointAddress(clientAddress);` and set up my service `ServiceReference1.Service1Client objService = new Service1Client(myBinding, myEndpoint);` Thank you for your help :)